# How can I show PO is the angle bisector of XPY?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

A, B, X, and Y are points on circle. Q is the intersection point of AB and XY. PA and PB are tangents.

Comment: Consider the angles subtended by the arcs at the centre of their circle.

Comment: Where did you get this from? It is false. Let $XY$ be sufficiently small, and intersect $AB$ near the circle. Then you can see that the line $PO$ doesn't always bisect $X\hat PY.$ Indeed you can make the angle $XPY$ much smaller than half of the angle $APB,$ so that the said bisector falls outside of the angle it's supposed to bisect.

Comment: XQY must be a straight and Q is fixed point.

Comment: Of course. My point was that you could make constructions following all your conditions, yet violating the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Extend PY to touch the circle at D. Mark intersection of PX and the circle as E. Connect D to E , this line intersect PO at C.We have :

$\angle XED=\angle XYD$

$\angle XCE=\angle DCY $

Therefore:

$\angle EDY=\angle YXE$

This is possible only if C  is coincident with Q, hence points  E and Y have equal distances from PO because PO is the symmetry axis of tangents PA and PB, therefore :

$\angle EQP=\angle YQP$

Hence triangles PQY and PQE are equal, so are the angles XPO and YPO, that means PO is the bisector of angle XPy.

Comment: what is the reason for this statement?

"This is possible only if C is coincident with Q."

Comment: Because arcs EY and XD are opposite to equal angles with same vertex.

Comment: You've proved something different. OP did not add the extra assumption you made. As I've commented above, without additional assumptions the claim is false as it stands.